# Kill all windows in a workspace in i3

Tags: i3

How do I kill all windows in a workspace if I can't open it?

I read this [suggestion](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/2865/is-there-a-way-to-killreset-a-whole-workspace/). But I can't do it because I cannot switch over to the workspace.

Answer (score 4):

it is working simply use below code

```
bindsym $mod+Shift+a focus parent,kill
```

it works for me

Comment: my new favorite binding

Answer (score 4):

In this case the trick lies in specifying a window selection for the bound command. As any individual i3 config file (`~/.config/i3/config`) might be structured very differently, the following example is purely for demonstration. Also, the use of the `Ctrl` key might be a bad real-world choice due to its proximity to the `Shift` key.

```
# Close focused window
bindsym $mod+q kill

# Close all windows on all workspaces (any class string)
bindsym $mod+Shift+q [class=”.*”] kill

# Close all windows on workspace 1 (name stored in $ws1)
bindsym $mod+Ctrl+1 [workspace=$ws1] kill
```

For further information have a look at the [i3 User's Guide](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#command_criteria).

Furthermore, despite its name the `kill` command does not actually kill the process but tries to use the `WM_DELETE` protocol. So depending on the respective behaviour a window might not close after all (most likely for a good reason).

Answer (score 2):

Use `i3-input -F <format> -P <prompt>`

This is how I use it in my config file:

`bindsym $mod+q exec i3-input -F '[workspace=^%s$] kill' -P 'kill workspace?'`

Every occurence of `%s` in the  string is replaced by the user input. Check `i3-input` man page for more details